# Embeding folder to exe in VS

Tags: c#, directory, embed, exe

I have wrote a code in VS17 which reading `gif` files by using the `path` of the folder and reading it content and stores it in a list.

```
for (int z = 0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
        {
            var d = new DataGridObject();

            d.MainName = list_MainName[z];
            d.Level = list_Level[z];

            d.ImageSource = new Uri(String.Format("{0}\\{1}.gif", Images_Path, list_MainName[z]), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            d.Level_Index = Initial_Lvl;
            d.Level_Goal = goallvl;

        }
```

However, i'm trying to build this code into an `exe` and i want to embed the folder with the images as a resource.

How can i embed a folder which contains images?

Thank you.

Comment: Add the folder, along with the files it contains, to the VS project, and choose [Embed Resource] build action on its content.

Comment: how do i use the images inside the folder once being saved as content? still need path?